# Building nested, generic, and array Types on runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I'm building a ExpressionConverter that allows me to convert expressions of type

`Expression<Func<A1, B1, C1, ..., Z1>>` to expressions of type `Expression<Func<A2, B2, C2, ..., Z2>>`

I have an existing map that maps type `A1` to type `A2`, `B1` to `B2`, `C1` to `C2` and so on.
So the simple map work easy.

```
private Type GetMappingType(Type type)
{
    var types = _mappingFinder.FindTypesFor(type).ToArray();
    if (types.Length == 0)
    {
        if (type.IsNested)
        {
            var nestedTypes = type.GetNestedTypes();
            var mappedNestedTypes = nestedTypes.Select(this.GetMappingType).ToArray();            
            //TODO: return the nested type        
        }
        if (type.HasElementType)
        {
            var mappedElementType = this.GetMappingType(type.GetElementType());
            //TODO: return the right container type with the mappedElementType
        }
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var genericTypes = type.GetGenericArguments();
            var mappedGenericTypes = genericTypes.Select(this.GetMappingType).ToArray();                    
            //TODO: return generictype with the mappedGenericTypes as arguments
        }
        return type;
    }
    if (types.Length == 1)
       return _types.Contains(types[0]) ? type : types[0];

    throw new Exception("Too many mapped types for " + type);
}
```

the problem cases are marked with `//TODO`
Since i only map `A1` to `A2` directly, i need to build those Array types like `A2[]` dynamically when i see a `A1[]` (generic case: `Func<A1>` to `Func<A2>`, ...)
can anyone point me to the right direction/documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For array :
`mappedElementType.MakeArrayType();`

For generics :
`return type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(mappedGenericTypes);`

But I missed the point for nested types, most probably because I never faced the problem by myself.